# Desserializing in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to use a Post Method (HttpPost) in Asp Net Core 3.1 and I revised articles about the new feature for using `System.Json.Text`. I tried to change the serializer to NewSoftJson without success because I tried to change the configuration in Startup.cs

This is my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "BackEnd Test C",
            Contact = new OpenApiContact() { Name = "Jane Doe", Email = "janedoe@emailprovider.com" }
        });

        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ProductDBContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("produto-api-in-memory");
    });

    services.AddScoped<IProdutoRepository, ProductRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();

    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

    services.AddScoped<NotificationContext>();

    services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add<NotificationFilter>());
}
```

But the serializer principal continues been System.Json.Text

I just would like how to solve the method below:

```
[HttpPost("Include")]
    public ActionResult<ProductDTO> Include([FromBody] ProductDTO productDTO)
    {     
        //var productDTO = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProductDTO>(parameterProduct);

        try
        {
            var product = mapper.Map<Product>(productDTO);
            var ok = productService.AddAsync(product);

            return Created($"/api/produtos/{product?.Id}", product?.Sku);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }

    }
```

I understand that `FromBody` not working for `System.Json.Text`, but I need alternatives that work to serialize my body using JSON to pass parameter to my method when I change the parameter how string works fine.

Thanks for any help, I just expended some hours trying to solve this scenario.

Comment: You have to show your code and  explain where do you got an error.

Comment: It indicates that you want to pass a string from body, then serilize the sting using newtonsoft?

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem? What's the actual JSON string? The classes? System.Text.Json works for the. vast majority of cases. It fails only for very unusual payload. If the *request* is wrong to begin with, deserialization will fail. If `ProductDTO` is an abstract class, the deserializer won't know what class to created

Comment: @Karney. covering up problems that always leads to worse problems. We have no idea what the problem is right now.  For all we know the JSON string is invalid, so it's JSON.NET that throws

Comment: The question as-is contains no useful information. `FromBody` has nothing to do with the deserializer, it tells ASP.NET Core where to find the string to process. If *any* of the assumptions in the question were true, ASP.NET Core wouldn't be able to process *any POST request*. That's obviously wrong

Comment: What's the error to begin with? *Is* there an error at all? Is the method called in the first place? Was the wrong URL used perhaps? Is `productDTO` null?

Comment: "but I need alternatives that work to serialize my body using JSON to pass parameter to my method when I change the parameter how string works fine" - this sentence is not quite clear. Please rephrase. Also, please check grammar before posting

Comment: Well, the fact is the post method didn't work fine. I research some foruns and articles that  in 3.1 version for Net Core occurred some modifications about the library responsible for serializartion, before that Newtonsoft.Json was used and now System.Text.Json is being used to this task. My question is how you guys is solving this? For me the method showed this behavior and I just would like to know if other issues can be causing this fail. Tks for attention.